# KMM Plugin: Unable to create KMM shared module in existing android project in latest android studio like Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

I was using Android Studio Giraffe and recently updated it to Hedgehog. The KMM plugin that was working perfectly stopped showing up in File -> New Module. I have provided details about Android Studio below, along with the KMM plugin version.

Android Studio version: **Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1**

KMM version: **com.jetbrains.kmm (0.8.1(231)-23)**

Comment: StackOverflow is not an issue tracker. Since you're having problems with KMM plugin, you can create an issue on [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue)

Comment: I have. Just want to put it out here so that if anyone finds a workaround, they can share it here.

Comment: Android studio has feature to enable this. Here is a comment from JetBrain team
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-27158/Import-is-failing-after-creation-of-new-module-if-project-dont-use-versionCatalog#focus=Comments-27-8195193.0-0

Comment: @NandhaKumar I think you should post this as an official response so it can be selected as an answer. You just put an end to HOURS of fumbling around.

Comment: Added as the answer. Thanks for pointing that out, @ChadMx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is hidden under **Advanced Settings** in Android Studio. Please refer this comment from JetBrain Team https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-27158/Import-is-failing-after-creation-of-new-module-if-project-dont-use-versionCatalog#focus=Comments-27-8195193.0-0